# Update a lot of buttons or checkboxes?

Tags: c#, dictionary, button, indicator

I need about 200 buttons that act as indicators with different colors and I have a list with true and false and wonder if there is a way to update them without having to write the names of the 200 buttons.
Something like this:

```
while (servoNumber != numberOfServos)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ListServo1Inputs[0 + inputToLookFor]) == true) 
    { 
        indicatorS1Di1.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        indicatorS1Di1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray; 
    }
}
```

But also that the `indicatorS1Di1.BackColor` counts up to S2 the next row in the loop. Something like: `indicatorS[increment number here]Di1.BackColor`

Maybe this would be a simple solution:

```
foreach (Control control in tabPage1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    MessageBox.Show(control.GetType().ToString());

    if (control.Name first letters == "indicatorDi")
    {
        control.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
    }
}
```

---

Thank you very much Rand Random!
With some small modifications this is what it looks like now:

[image: Final look]

Comment: How did or are you creating the buttons?

Comment: Just adding them from toolbox

Comment: And you already did name the buttons with the scheme indicatorS1Di1 (SxDix) so you have them up to 200 - indicatorS200Di200? or something similar? Or simply phrased whats your naming convention exactly ?

Comment: I have only added about 20 buttons so far and named them as above but anything can be changed at this stage.
Its s1di1, s1di2, s1di3 up to 12 and then starting over with s2di1
But as I said, that can be changed if it simplifies something else.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your load event build a list of controls.

```
_buttons = new List<Button>(); //this is a field and not a local variable in the load event
for (var i = 0; i < ListServo1Inputs.Count; i++)
{
    _buttons.Add((Button)this.Controls.Find($"indicatorS{i}Di1", true).First());
}
```

to update your color use the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ListServo1Inputs.Count; i++)
{
    //you can now use the same index for _controls and ListServo1Inputs - since you constructed a list of controls based on ListServo1Inputs in the loaded event
    _buttons[i].BackColor = Convert.ToBoolean(ListServo1Inputs[i]) ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.DarkGray;
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comment you made.

I would create the buttons dynamically.
In your form you will need a button with a click event and a panel.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //stores the booleans in a list
    private readonly List<bool> _values = new List<bool>();

    //I use a random to generate the booleans _random.Next(2) will produce either 0 or 1 and _random.Next(2) == 1 will give true on 1 and false on 0
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //fill the list
        FillValues();

        //iterate over the list
        for (var index = 0; index < _values.Count; index++)
        {
            //create a button for each entry
            var btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "Values" + index; //dont need the name, but you can fill it as you see fit
            btn.Width = 70; //set the width as you desire
            btn.Height = 20; //set the height as you desire
            btn.Text = btn.Name; //set a text if you like to, I used the .Name

            //some math to position the buttons, I here use a grid of 12 since you mentioned your naming scheme changes at 12 S1Di1 -> S1Di12 and than S2Di1 -> S2Di12
            btn.Top = (index / 12) * (btn.Height + btn.Margin.Top); 
            btn.Left = (index % 12) * (btn.Width + btn.Margin.Left);

            panel1.Controls.Add(btn); //add the button to a panel thats inside your form, only the buttons that get created here should be inside that panel nothing more
        }

        //update the colors of the button
        UpdateColors();
    }

    private void FillValues()
    {
        //clear the values, before filling it
        _values.Clear();

        //you mentioned 200 buttons, so here is a for loop for 200 entries and fill the values with a bool
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            _values.Add(_random.Next(2) == 1);

        //of course you dont need to clear the list and re-add the items everytime this method gets called, you can check if (_values.Count == 0) and only than add the items and in else set the new values with _values[i] = newValue - its just the lazy way :)
    }
    private void UpdateColors()
    {
        //iterate over the list and set the panels Controls[index] to the color - the index will match with the list since you have created the buttons based on the list previously
        for (int i = 0; i < _values.Count; i++)
            panel1.Controls[i].BackColor = _values[i] ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.DarkGray;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to have new bools in list fill the values
        FillValues();

        //update the colors
        UpdateColors(); 
    }
}
```

With this you will end up with:
[image]

When you hit the button1:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating these buttons yourself, you could put them in a dictionary with your incremental names as keys.

Then you could change the value with:

```
ServoButtonDict[$"indicatorS{incrementalNumber}Di1"].BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a foreach loop, that way you could iterate over the button dynamically.

```
foreach (var indicator in ListServoInputs) {
    if (indicator.Checked) {
        indicator.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
    } else {
        indicator.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    }
}
```

Or you could simplify it more with a [ternary operator](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary) which is great for simple but lengthy if/else statements.

```
foreach (var indicator in ListServoInputs) {
    indicator.BackColor = indicator.Checked ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.DarkGray;
```

Comment: Hmm do you mean that I put the names of the buttons in the ListServoInputs list?
The ListServoInputs in this case contains 200 rows of true of false

Comment: Oh, I would suggest creating a List<Button> on initialization, this would make ListServoInputs unnecessary as each button could already holds on/off through BackColor. You could init the list by incrementing through the button names using a delegate or bulk initialization.